# Prevent Duplicate Entries in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following in my PHP.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO savesearch (user, searchedFor, sortOrder, buildURLString, aspectFilters, oneSignalId, totalEntries)
  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
  $stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $user, $searchedFor, $sortOrder, $buildURLString, $aspectFilters, $oneSignalId, $totalEntries);

  // set parameters and execute
  $user = $_POST['user'];
  $searchedFor = $_POST["searchedFor"];
  $sortOrder = $_POST["sortOrder"];
  $buildURLString = $_POST["buildURLString"];
  $aspectFilters = $_POST["aspectFilters"];
  $oneSignalId = $_POST["oneSignalId"];
  $totalEntries = $_POST["totalEntries"];

  if ($stmt->execute()) {
    $output->success = true;
    echo json_encode($output);
  } else {
    $error->error = mysqli_error($conn);
    echo json_encode($error);
  }
```

However, IGNORE is not being picked up, it continues to add entries. Is there another good way to fix this?

Id like to see if the USER and the URL is the same, dont add, echo duplicate entry.

Comment: Use unique constraint http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique/

Comment: Have you indexed the particular column, for which you want to avoid duplicates as PK?

Comment: make unique attribute in database..and check affected rows ..if any row affected then send success response

Comment: Use Unique key constraints and you also validate duplicate check validation from frontend. follow this https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IGNORE` is actually mostly for the opposite of what you want here. Instead, you can amend your MySQL table something like:

`ALTER TABLE savesearch ADD UNIQUE KEY(user, buildURLString)`

Then remove your `IGNORE` keyword

Comment: ok i was able to add those as unique. in PHP, how would i echo that out?

Comment: thanks for the tip. for anyone else seeing this, this is what I needed for the SQL.  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX WHATEVER_HERE
ON tbl_name(row_name,row_name);